# Copy a row from one spreadsheet to a different tab in another speadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to move prospects from spreadsheet 1 into leads in spreadsheet 2. A row from spreadsheet 1 has to be copied to spreadsheet 2 upon selecting the value "prospect" in the dropdown. After its copied to the second spreadsheet, the row should get deleted. I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
function onEdit(event) {

    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Ycv8");
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var ts = ts.getSheetByName("Leads");


    if(s.getName() == "Radhika" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Prospect") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); 
    var target = ts.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);}   

}
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Hello. Can you link us to the documentation to the library you are getting `SpreadsheetApp` variable from? On first glance, I think the problem is with `var ts = ts.getSheetByName("Leads");` perhaps you mean to try `tss.getSheetByName('Leads');`

Comment: Hi @ChiragRavindra Thanks for pointing it, I changed it to 'tss' but it's still not working. Here's the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Comment: @SaiChaitanya : What is not working, mention what issue / error you have, debug your code, put Logger.log() statements.

Comment: @NitinDhomse When I change the status of a particular row to "prospect" (I have created a dropdown using data validation), I want the data of that row to be copied to an external spreadsheet. I see this error in the log - "You do not have permission to call openById at onEdit(Code:4)"  In the above code, I'm accessing the second sheet by using the function openByID(), do I need provide any permission to access second sheet?

Comment: You can't use SpreadsheetApp.openById in onEdit() trigger. I think this has something to do with [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions). Notice that you're able to use SpreadsheetApp.openById if you place it inside a regular function.